# Session loss in dotProject

Tags: apache-2.2, php, session

I'm setting up a [dotProject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DotProject) installation, but my session is lost on every pageload and I get redirected to the login page. It seems the session variable "dotproject" is missing from every link. When I forge links manually (http://localhost/dotproject/index.php?m=ticketsmith&dotproject=....) the pages work fine.

Please advise.

**EDIT:**

I get the following warnings when enabling debug mode:

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send
>   session cache limiter - headers
>   already sent (output started at
>   C:\Apache\htdocs\dotproject\index.php:24)
>   in
>   C:\Apache\htdocs\dotproject\includes\session.php
>   on line 207 Warning: Cannot modify
>   header information - headers already
>   sent by (output started at
>   C:\Apache\htdocs\dotproject\index.php:24)
>   in
>   C:\Apache\htdocs\dotproject\index.php
>   on line 64 Warning: Cannot modify
>   header information - headers already
>   sent by (output started at
>   C:\Apache\htdocs\dotproject\index.php:24)
>   in
>   C:\Apache\htdocs\dotproject\index.php
>   on line 65 Warning: Cannot modify
>   header information - headers already
>   sent by (output started at
>   C:\Apache\htdocs\dotproject\index.php:24)
>   in
>   C:\Apache\htdocs\dotproject\index.php
>   on line 66 Warning: Cannot modify
>   header information - headers already
>   sent by (output started at
>   C:\Apache\htdocs\dotproject\index.php:24)
>   in
>   C:\Apache\htdocs\dotproject\index.php
>   on line 67 Warning: Cannot modify
>   header information - headers already
>   sent by (output started at
>   C:\Apache\htdocs\dotproject\index.php:24)
>   in
>   C:\Apache\htdocs\dotproject\index.php
>   on line 219

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running Firefox, you should run [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647/), and inspect the cookies returned by the server.
The problem could be related to an invalid hostname, causing the browser to reject the session cookie.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't get back any cookies at all...

Comment: In index.php, could you uncomment line 24 (`error_reporting(E_ALL)`) and place any error messages here? I've a feelng that you get `Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent`. How did you upload dotProjects files, and edit these?

Comment: Thanks again for the help... I've updated my question based on your suggestion. Regarding your question: I don't exactly understand what you mean by uploading dotProjects files (I unzipped them on a server locally).

Comment: Did you strip any comments? Because line 24 in index.php contains the line `error_reporting(E_ALL);` (latest version from Sourceforge). If you don't mind, could you run `phpinfo();`, and upload the result somewhere?

Comment: Here you go:
http://akosch.rewq.org/info.htm

Comment: Nevermind: got it working by tweaking php.ini... Thank you for your time!

Comment: COuld you post your solution? Others might find it helpful too ;)

Comment: I needed to enable output_buffering in the php.ini file.